# What does one call the strategy of using "pre-password transforms" as passwords?

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, terminology

Suppose that instead of using, say, `Google, let me in!` as my Google password, I used some consistent transform of this string, say `ZWE1NjMyNm`?

What search keywords would be helpful to search for information on the general idea of using "pre-password transforms" as passwords?

Comment: I'd start with searching for "insecure".  A consistent transform can still be universally broken by a mildly targeted attacker and is almost certainly highly vulnerable to things like frequency attacks, even by automated analysis.  This is not a good idea.  It may be a half measure better than using the same password, but not significantly.

Comment: if you are doing something that requires a computer to process it, then use a password manager and random passwords.  If you are doing something that is remotely human readable, the algorithm is able to be reverse engineered.  Also, we aren't talking about reversing a hash, we are talking about analysis of what is actually involved in producing it.  Those are NOT the same question.

Comment: yes, but slow hashes don't protect against related passwords.  If you had related passwords that you then ran through some convolution or hash, it is still trivial to guess the other inputs and test them.  You don't have to try randomly, so the runtime doesn't matter.  You are confusing finding random passwords with a rainbow table versus attacking a specific user across sites.

Comment: Google let me in is related to your google account as it is descriptive of it.  You are trying to make easy to remember passwords in to something harder to recognize, but having it be harder to recognize is no more secure than the initial password is.

Comment: This is snake oil - false security, which is arguably worse than not doing it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard of a specific name for these types of password transformations.  However, they often involve the use of a "master password" and "site password".  You can do some searching based on those terms and filter out the irrelevant results.

Here are a few examples of similar schemes that are implemented through software:

- http://angel.net/~nic/passwd.current.html
- https://saltthepass.com/
- http://masterpasswordapp.com/

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, and not giving me irrelevant lectures!!!  Your answer does wonders for my badly-shaken faith in this kind of QA site.  I wish I could upvote it many more times.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a *witty password*: a password which relies on the user knowing some specific generation method.

This is bad. Witty passwords are not secure passwords; they more are quite the opposite. When you use a "witty password", you rely on the attacker being less smart than you. Self-confidence notwithstanding, this always fails. Attackers know about such password generation methods; in fact, they have access to the Internet so they can read about them *right here*. Compounding the effect is cross-site propagation: if your password on one site is stolen (e.g. through hostile hijack of the server), then the attacker may observe your password for that site, and infer your "secret rule", thereby deducing the passwords you used on many other sites.

The important word is "consistent". You don't want that. Though consistence is generally good for all intellectual endeavours, for passwords it is really bad. You don't want consistency; you need **randomness**. Only randomness yields security. Randomness is what the attacker cannot guess, precisely because it is random, not witty.

Ideally, you would use random passwords, with at least (say) 30 bits of entropy per password, and (crucially) a different password for each site. That's the most important part: it should not be feasible to deduce your password on one site from knowledge of your password on any other site. If you have trouble remembering all these passwords, I suggest using a password manager such as [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) or [KeePass](http://keepass.info/). Alternatively, *write down* your passwords in a safe place (this can be a piece of paper in your wallet; wallets have good physical security, because you *care* about them).

Comment: I've never heard the term "witty password" - do you have a reference to the term?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace - pretty sure it is more a class of things than a formal description.  I've also heard "clever" password.  They key is that it assumes that the user's system is smarter than what the attacker can reverse engineer, which is almost always a bad assumption and certainly not a reliable one.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about either a witty (or clever) password or a key derivation algorithm (that is being shoehorned in to producing a "concealed" password).  Neither provides any additional security beyond the original password complexity. Either the system is insecure because it is too simple and able to be reverse engineered, resulting in catastrophic failures of multiple accounts, or it is so complex that it requires a computer to do the processing for you, at which point there is precisely zero reason not to use a randomly generated password that is encrypted and stored in a password manager.  Because of this, there are not existing systems that use this approach as they would be inherently insecure.

There is absolutely no case where this is a useful idea that provides any meaningful security advantage at all.  A human processable system might be marginally better than having the same password for every account, but you don't achieve meaningful security if there is any relationship between the passwords of different accounts, which this explicitly builds.

You seem to be mixing up secure password hashing for server password storage (designed to protect a single site) vs security for passwords for a user across multiple sites.

Comment: I have updated to include the names of the two things you seem to be describing, but there isn't an exact term because what you are talking about is universally considered a bad idea.  Despite the fact you may not want to hear it, it is important to point out that these are bad ideas and thus it IS an important part of an answer.